# Add a project dependency to another project in Android studio

Tags: android, library-project

I have a existing project say A which has dependencies over a few projects. Now I want to make this project A as a library project for Project B. What I have done so far is in the build.gradle of Project A, I have changed the plugin from "android:application" to "android:library", My question is how to use the project A as a library module to Project B. When i add a new Module and give its dependency to Project A the build files are not generated in the new module. If a create a new Project for B and then import Project A as a module i get errors on the dependencies used for Project A. Please suggest how to go about.

Answer (score 4):

Edit `build.gradle` of your module (not the root build.gradle).

Replace `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` with `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`.

Remove `applicationId` from the same build.gradle project as described below:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.packageName"//remove this line
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

After this sync your gradle file. Now your project has been marked as library, but to create a release version of library you need to use this library into a module, so we will create a new module in the same project.

For creating new module go to:

> File-> New Module-> (choose)phone and tablet Application->next...

Let's say the new module created is B. Now add dependency of library A on module B as described by [user @Sam Rad here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

Run your project, after succesfull Run you will find a release version of library in folder

> A->build->outputs-> (.aar package Release version)

Hope this will help

Comment: Before I do this I want a help. The Project A which I want to make as a Library is a application project which has many modules dependencies. I would be grateful if you could tell me how to convert this project into a library project first up.
I have changed the plugin to android:application to android:library but it doesn't do all the trick. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: @Saraschandraa I have edited the answer and if you use the release version of library then it will provide all its dependencies alongwith

Comment: every time i create the library module and then create a application module which has the dependency over the library module, I have problem with the R file. Can you help me out how to fix this.

Comment: 1.Go to Build->clean project

Comment: then go to File->invalidate caches and restrart->invalidate and restart